# Bulk import from csv table fields into sql table

Tags: sql-server, csv

Please suggest, how i can bult insert fields from csv table to sql server.

I browse over the internet, but nothing worked for me. A sample i have taken from internet

```
INSERT INTO MENU_MASTER ([MENU_ID], [MENU_DES], [MENU_OPTION], [MENU_OPTIO_DES],[COUNTRY],[REQUIRED],[PARENT_MENU],[PARENT_MENU_OPTION],[MENU_DESCRIPTION],[PARENT_DISPLAY_NAME],[MENU_ORDER])

SELECT A.[MENU_ID], A.[MENU_DES], A.[MENU_OPTION], A.[MENU_OPTIO_DES],A.[COUNTRY],A.[REQUIRED],A.[PARENT_MENU],A.[PARENT_MENU_OPTION],A.[MENU_DESCRIPTION],A.[PARENT_DISPLAY_NAME],A.[MENU_ORDER]
FROM OPENROWSET
('Microsoft OLEDB.4.0','Database=C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\bulkcopy.csv','Administrator')
```

Output is

Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft OLEDB.4.0" has not been registered.

Eventhough i have registered Microsoft OLEDB.4.0" from cmd propmpt

Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe it's the name? But why don't you use simply BULK INSERT to read the data of a csv-file?

Comment: I have tried the folowing , but getting error for the same. Cannot find the path. Could you please suggest with sample query

Comment: If you JUST use `BULK INSERT`, you take the provider issue out of the picture. BTW note that the provider AND the CSV file need to be on the SERVER, not the client.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: BULK INSERT MENU_MASTER ([MENU_ID], [MENU_DES], [MENU_OPTION], [MENU_OPTIO_DES],[COUNTRY],[REQUIRED],[PARENT_MENU],[PARENT_MENU_OPTION],[MENU_DESCRIPTION],[PARENT_DISPLAY_NAME],[MENU_ORDER])

SELECT A.[MENU_ID], A.[MENU_DES], A.[MENU_OPTION], A.[MENU_OPTIO_DES],A.[COUNTRY],A.[REQUIRED],A.[PARENT_MENU],A.[PARENT_MENU_OPTION],A.[MENU_DESCRIPTION],A.[PARENT_DISPLAY_NAME],A.[MENU_ORDER]
FROM OPENROWSET
('Microsoft OLEDB.4.0','Database=C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\bulkcopy.csv','Administrator')

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Incorrect syntax near '(', please correct me

Comment: I'm not going to correct that jumbled mess but I strongly suggest you do not use desktop or any user specific area to hold your file. Use somewhere more generic like `C:\Temp`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I use `BULK INSERT`:

```
BULK INSERT [DB].[Schema].[Table] 
    FROM 'C:\file.csv' 
    WITH (MAXERRORS=0
,FIELDTERMINATOR=','
,TABLOCK
,CodePage='ACP'
,FIRSTROW=1
)
```

see also [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Comment: The file does not exist in the path

Comment: Obviously you have to edit my code for your file, from your question: replace "C:\file.csv" to "C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\bulkcopy.csv". If you did, check the file location is correct.

Comment: The same has been done earlier, but same exception  
The file does not exist in the path

Comment: Also, is sql server installed on the same machine as where the file is located? Sql server will look for it's 'own' C: drive.

Comment: Yes, i went through all the stuffs that has been told in the internet, but still exception occurs

Comment: Could it maybe have something to do with permissions? You could try relocating the file to, say C:\BULK\bulkcopy.csv, and try from there.

Comment: Run this in SSMS: `EXEC xp_dirtree '<path to the folder that holds your file>'`. What do you get?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, thats a pretty nifty function, didn't know about that.

Comment: Yes quite nifty and often the best way to ascertain how a path 'looks' from SQL Servers point of view!.. but it is 'undocumented'... http://www.mssqlcity.com/articles/undoc/undocextsp.htm